# what is the uses cases in which order in key value associative container is useful

Tags: c++

I am wondering in which uses cases, we can be interested by having an ordered associative container.

In other terms, why use `std::map` and no `std::unorderd_map`

Comment: This would be determined solely by your business requirements. The type which will be put into the ordered map of course needs to be less-than comparable, but this would also be dependent on your problem domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use an ordered map when you need to be able to iterate over the keys in an ordered fashion.

Comment: Actually you can iterate an `unordered_map` like a regular map

Answer (score 1):

As Mat pointed out, it depends on whether you need to access your elements in sorted order.  Also, map has *guaranteed*, *worst-case* logarithmic access time (in the number of elements), whereas unordered map has *average* constant access time.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for using `map` instead of `unordered_map` is that `map` is in standard and for sure you have it. Some companies have policy not to use definitions from `tr1`.
But you ask when order is important - it is needed for operations like `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, `set_union`, `set_intersection` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the comparison between unordered containers is needed, the complexity
might be an issue.
It seems to be difficult to implement `operator==`/`operator!=` between
unordered containers efficiently.
N3290 §23.2.5/11 says

> the complexity of operator== ... is
>   proportional to ... N^2 in the worst
>   case, where N is a.size().

while other containers have linear complexity.

Answer (score -1):

Unordered_map use more memory than map. If there is a constraint in memory then its recommended to use map. So the operations become slower when using unordered_map

**EDIT**

Quoting from the wiki article

```
It is similar to the map class in the C++ standard library but has different 
constraints. As its name implies, unlike the map class, the elements of an 
unordered_map are not ordered. This is due to the use of hashing to store objects.
unordered_map can still be iterated through like a regular map.
```